Statically get all attributes of class
I want to be able to call a static method of a class (or classmethod) to only get the attributes of that class. By the attributes of the class, I mean the ones that are set in the constructor of the class. I also use inheritance, so I would like to be able to do this for both MyClass and MyChildClass.
class MyClass():
   def __init__(self, x = None, y = None):
      self.a = x
      self.b = y

   @classmethod
   def get_all_attr(cls):
      return ?

class MyChildClass():
   def __init__(self, z = None, **kwargs):
      self.c = z
      super().__init__(**kwargs)

>>> MyClass.get_all_attr()
['a', 'b']
>>> MyChildClass.get_all_attr()
['c', 'a', 'b']


I know that __dir__() exists, but I have not been able to call this statically. I've also tried MyClass.__dict__().keys(), but this also won't work.

literally just return dir(MyClass), what else do you need?

@ŁukaszKwieciński cannot reproduce. Running your suggested code returns a list of class methods ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'get_all_attr']  But it doesn't return 'a' and 'b' which is what the OP asked.

Attributes can be added dynamically, not only by the constructor, and not only at instance creation time. They can be different (number of) attributes on different instances, so which of those variations do you want your static method to report on, even when you don't have any instances yet? This is not well-defined. You'll need to add clarification to remove any such ambiguity.

At the very least, why would this be a static method, rather than a class method?

@chepner good point, I changed it

And really, you want get the attributes dynamically; the trivial static definition of MyClass.get_all_attr would be to simply return ['a', 'b']. You want to query the cls argument to somehow discover which attributes are defined, because (as the subclassing example demonstrates) you don't know statically which class's attributes will need to be returned.

Well, maybe I should have just asked the question as my final use case: I want to get these attributes as strings because I want to check if a csv file contains the right headers to create an instance of MyClass for each row. The MyChildClass is only used when a user specifies that they also want the functionality associated with self.c , then it will be checked if the file contains the right headers to create an instance of MyChildClass with MyChildClass.get_all_attr(). Hope that clarifies it.

class MyClass:
    attribute1 = "Value1"
    attribute2 = "Value2"
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_attributes():
        return {attr: value for attr, value in MyClass.__dict__.items() if not attr.startswith('__') and not callable(getattr(MyClass, attr))}

# Calling the static method to get the attributes
attributes = MyClass.get_attributes()
print(attributes)


Just a code block dump without any explanation how this answers the question is not helpful.
